# Rename Domain joined computer in powershell with AES Key file and secure string txt file

Tags: powershell, rename, credentials

need some help here its driving me crazy.

I have an aeskey file and that secure string txt file and the below is my code

```
$User = "domain\username"
$PasswordFile = "c:\key\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "c:\key\AES.key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)


Rename-Computer -NewName "$Computername-test2" -DomainCredential $MyCredential -Force
```

I keep getting an access denied, can someone please help me in the right direction, i'm trying to basically have my aeskey file and secure string on domain machines so tech team can run the rename command since they don't have the access to rename domain joined computers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you generate the txt file with the exported secure string in the first place?

Comment: Is the computer in AD? Also, is your WMI service running; to include the firewall rule being enabled - *may include DCOM as well*?

Comment: yeah computer is in AD, sorry i'm super new to this haha

Comment: got the text file by creating it following this guide here https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/

Comment: Can you try to rename the system using a separate name? One that is not in AD already; so don't create the object.

Comment: so the $computername -test2 is actually not on the domain